# Solutions to fair distribution programming problems

Tags: algorithm

I have run into a wall since I attended a coding contest. I think this problem falls into the category of fair distribution, but I am not sure.
I am attaching the problem [here](http://pastebin.com/xd3eywKj).

I have come out with an empirical formula so which I tested successfully for 3 iterations attached [here](http://pastebin.com/t9JyrUce).

I am unable to come up with a working code that can solve this programming problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why did I get a downvote for this question? anybody, please help me understand so that I don't make the same mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throughout the solution, I use `A` for hotel and `B` for house

Let us define 3 types of arrangements:

1. Arrangement ending with `A`||`B`, that is hotel on left and house on right.
2. Arrangement ending with `B`||`A`, that is house on left and hotel on right.
3. Arrangement ending with `B`||`B`, that is house on both sides.

Let us denote the respective arrays:

- Array `one[i]` denotes number of arrangements of type 1 having street length `i`
- Array `two[i]` denotes number of arrangements of type 2 having street length `i`
- Array `three[i]` denotes number of arrangements of type 3 having street length `i`

Any arrangement of type 1, can be extended when the street length increases by `1` as follows:

`B`||`A`
`A`||`B`  [A Type 2 arrangement]

`B`||`B`
`A`||`B`  [A Type 3 arrangement]

Any arrangement of type 2, can be extended when the street length increases by `1` as follows:

`A`||`B`
`B`||`A`  [A Type 1 arrangement]

`B`||`B`
`B`||`A`  [A Type 3 arrangement]

Any arrangement of type 3, can be extended when the street length increases by `1` as follows:

`A`||`B`
`B`||`B`  [A Type 1 arrangement]

`B`||`A`
`B`||`B`  [A Type 2 arrangement]

`B`||`B`
`B`||`B`  [A Type 3 arrangement]

When street length is `1`:

`one[1] = two[1] = three[1] = 1` (As explained in the sample test case)

When street length is `i`:

`one[i] = two[i-1] + three[i-1]`

`two[i] = one[i-1] + three[i-1]`

`three[i] = one[i-1] + two[i-1] + three[i-1]`

For a street length of size `n`, your answer is `(one[n] + two[n] + three[n]) % 10^9+7`

As `n` can be very huge, you need to come up with a general formula for the value of `(one[n] + two[n] + three[n]) % 10^9+7`

```
For n=1: result = 3
For n=2: result = 7
For n=3: result = 17
For n=4: result = 41
```

Verify the above results yourself!!!

**Edit:** You can use Matrix exponentiation to find out the result for different values of `n` in `O(logn)` time. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829549/general-formula-for-a-recurrence-relation) for more details!!!

You can use a matrix to represent the recurrence relation.

```
(one[n+1])   =   ( 0 1 1 ) (one[n])
(two[n+1])       ( 1 0 1 ) (two[n])
(three[n+1])     ( 1 1 1 ) (three[n])
```

With this representation, it's feasible to compute values for large `n`, by matrix exponentation (modulo `10^9+7`), using exponentation by squaring. That'll give you the result in O(log n) time.

```
(one[n])    = ( 0 1 1 )^(n-1) (1)
(two[n])      ( 1 0 1 )       (1)
(three[n])    ( 1 1 1 )       (1)
```

Happy Coding....

Comment: So as I gather from your solution, I think the easiest approach to this problem is recursion. Would you advise that? Or is there a better method?

Comment: The better method is called *fast matrix exponentiation*!! Check out the link in my answer

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. By the way, does this fall into the category of fair distribution? I am not sure actually.

Comment: Simply, one can say that its a question based on `arrangements and combinations`. The solution also has properties of a programming technique called `dynamic programming` where we can calculate new values based on previous values, just like: `one[i] = two[i-1] + three[i-1]`

Comment: awesome! Thanks!! by the way, this is a side request, I had one more question. Do you know any method to get the GDP using the data in CSV provided here? http://data.worldbank.org/data-catalog/world-development-indicators. I can't understand which parameters to take to evaluate the GDP. There are 1345 parameters for each country so I don't know which ones to take.

Comment: Its better if you ask a separate question on SO, so that anyone can help you out.

Comment: thanks a lot! you have been a lot of help! #respect