# General formula for a recurrence relation?

Tags: algorithm, formula, recurrence

I was solving a coding question, and found out the following relation to find the number of possible arrangements:

`one[1] = two[1] = three[1] = 1`

`one[i] = two[i-1] + three[i-1]`

`two[i] = one[i-1] + three[i-1]`

`three[i] = one[i-1] + two[i-1] + three[i-1]`

I could have easily used a **for loop** to find out the values of the individual arrays till `n`, but the value of `n` is of the order `10^9`, and I won't be able to iterate from `1` to such a huge number.

For every value of `n`, I need to output the value of `(one[n] + two[n] + three[n]) % 10^9+7` in `O(1)` time.

Some results:

- For n = 1, result = 3
- For n = 2, result = 7
- For n = 3, result = 17
- For n = 4, result = 41

I was not able to find out a general formula for `n` for the above after spending hours on it. Can someone help me out.

**Edit:**

```
n = 1, result(1) = 3
n = 2, result(2) = 7
n = 3, result(3) = result(2)*2 + result(1) = 17
n = 4, result(4) = result(3)*2 + result(2) = 41
```

So, `result(n) = result(n-1)*2 + result(n-2)` OR
    `T(n) = 2T(n-1) + T(n-2)`

Comment: Did you try paper, pencil and some algebra?

Comment: Yes.. tried pencil an paper to find out a pattern. Couldn't find it. Not so good as Algebra though...

Comment: Well, I can tell you that, at first glance, it doesn't look too difficult to figure out. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to engage into it. Try again, harder this time.

Comment: By the way, `result[n] = one[n] + two[n] + three[n]` looks as not belonging there.

Comment: @FDavidov: Edited. Removed `result[n]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a matrix to represent the recurrence relation. (I've renamed `one`, `two`, `three` to `a`, `b`, `c`).

```
(a[n+1]) = ( 0 1 1 ) (a[n])
(b[n+1])   ( 1 0 1 ) (b[n])
(c[n+1])   ( 1 1 1 ) (c[n])
```

With this representation, it's feasible to compute values for large `n`, by matrix exponentation (modulo your large number), using exponentation by squaring. That'll give you the result in O(log n) time.

```
(a[n]) = ( 0 1 1 )^(n-1) (1)
(b[n])   ( 1 0 1 )       (1)
(c[n])   ( 1 1 1 )       (1)
```

Here's some Python that implements this all from scratch:

```
# compute a*b mod K where a and b are square matrices of the same size
def mmul(a, b, K):
    n = len(a)
    return [
        [sum(a[i][k] * b[k][j] for k in xrange(n)) % K for j in xrange(n)]
        for i in xrange(n)]

# compute a^n mod K where a is a square matrix
def mpow(a, n, K):
    if n == 0: return [[i == j for i in xrange(len(a))] for j in xrange(len(a))]
    if n % 2: return mmul(mpow(a, n-1, K), a, K)
    a2 = mpow(a, n//2, K)
    return mmul(a2, a2, K)

M = [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]

def f(n):
    K = 10**9+7
    return sum(sum(a) for a in mpow(M, n-1, K)) % K

print f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)
print f(10 ** 9)
```

Output:

```
3 7 17 41
999999966
```

It runs effectively instantly, even for the n=10**9 case.

Comment: It's a standard trick used for fast computation of recurrence relations (eg: Fibonacci).